# C++ Как узнать, запущен ли конкретный процесс по имени

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Здравствуйте, имею функцию проверки на запущенность процесса.

Вот код:

```
bool ProcessRunning(const char* name)
{
    HANDLE SnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (SnapShot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (!Process32First(SnapShot, &procEntry))
        return false;

    do
    {
        if (strcmp(procEntry.szExeFile, name) == 0)
            return true;
    } while (Process32Next(SnapShot, &procEntry));

    return false;
}
```

Пишу код в Visual Studio 2015, при компиляции моего кода такая ошибка:

```
argument of type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
```

Что только не делал, чтобы решить эту проблему.

Заголовочный файл tlhelp32.h подключен, что можно с этим сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Либо меняйте Charset проекта на неюникодный, либо используйте `WCHAR* name` в качестве параметра функции.